# Round Robin Scheduler

Tags: java, scheduler, round-robin

I need to implement a "round-robin" scheduler with a job class that I cannot modify. Round-robin scheduler should process the job that has been waiting the longest first, then reset timer to zero. If two jobs have same wait time, lower id is processed first. The job class only gives three values (job id, remaining duration, and priority(which is not needed for this). each job has a start time, so only a couple of jobs may be available during first cycle, few more next cycle, etc. Since the "job array" I am calling is different every time I call it, I'm not sure how to store the wait times.

This is the job class:

```
public class Jobs{
private int[] stas = new int[0];
private int[] durs = new int[0];
private int[] lefs = new int[0];
private int[] pris = new int[0];
private int[] fins = new int[0];
private int clock;

public Jobs()
{
    this("joblist.csv");
}

public Jobs(String filename)
{
    BufferedReader fp = null;
    String line = "";
    String[] b = null;
    int[] tmp;
    try
    {
        fp = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        while((line = fp.readLine()) != null)
        {
            b = line.split(",");
            if(b.length == 3)
            {
                try
                {
                    int sta = Integer.parseInt(b[0]);
                    //System.out.println("sta: " + b[0]);
                    int dur = Integer.parseInt(b[1]);
                    //System.out.println("dur: " + b[1]);
                    int pri = Integer.parseInt(b[2]);
                    //System.out.println("pri: " + b[2]);
                    stas = app(stas, sta);
                    //System.out.println("stas: " + Arrays.toString(stas));
                    durs = app(durs, dur);
                    //System.out.println("durs: " + Arrays.toString(durs));
                    lefs = app(lefs, dur);
                    //System.out.println("lefs: " + Arrays.toString(lefs));
                    pris = app(pris, pri);
                    //System.out.println("pris: " + Arrays.toString(pris));
                    fins = app(fins, -1);
                    //System.out.println("fins: " + Arrays.toString(fins));
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
            }
        }
        fp.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    clock = 0;
}

public boolean done()
{
    boolean done = true;
    for(int i=0; done && i<lefs.length; i++)
        if(lefs[i]>0) done=false;
    return done;
}

public int getClock() { return clock; }
public int[][] getJobs()
{
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<stas.length; i++)
        if(stas[i]<=clock && lefs[i]>0)
            count++;
    int[][] jobs = new int[count][3];
    count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<stas.length; i++)
        if(stas[i]<=clock && lefs[i]>0)
        {
            jobs[count] = new int[]{i, lefs[i], pris[i]};
            count++;
        }
    return jobs;
}

public int cycle() { return cycle(-1); }
public int cycle(int j)
{
    if(j>=0 && j<lefs.length && clock>=stas[j] && lefs[j]>0)
    {
        lefs[j]--;
        if(lefs[j] == 0) fins[j] = clock+1;
    }
    clock++;
    return clock;
}

private int[] app(int[] a, int b)
{
    int[] tmp = new int[a.length+1];
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) tmp[i] = a[i];
    tmp[a.length] = b;
    return tmp;
}

public String report()
{
    String r = "JOB,PRIORITY,START,DURATION,FINISH,DELAY,PRI*DELAY\n";
    float dn=0;
    float pdn=0;
    for(int i=0; i<stas.length; i++)
    {
        if(fins[i]>=0)
        {
            int delay = ((fins[i]-stas[i])-durs[i]);
            r+= ""+i+","+pris[i]+","+stas[i]+","+durs[i]+","+fins[i]+","+delay+","+(pris[i]*delay)+"\n";
            dn+= delay;
            pdn+= pris[i]*delay;
        }
        else
        {
            int delay = ((clock*10-stas[i])-durs[i]);
            r+= ""+i+","+pris[i]+","+stas[i]+","+durs[i]+","+fins[i]+","+delay+","+(pris[i]*delay)+"\n";
            dn+= delay;
            pdn+= pris[i]*delay;
        }
    }
    if(stas.length>0)
    {
        r+= "Avg,,,,,"+(dn/stas.length)+","+pdn/stas.length+"\n";
    }
    return r;
}

public String toString()
{
    String r = "There are "+stas.length+" jobs:\n";
    for(int i=0; i<stas.length; i++)
    {
        r+= "  JOB "+i+": START="+stas[i]+" DURATION="+durs[i]+" DURATION_LEFT="+lefs[i]+" PRIORITY="+pris[i]+"\n";
    }
    return r;
}
```

I don't need full code, just an idea of how to store wait times and cycle the correct job.

Comment: This seems to work: 
    for(int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++)
       {
        waitTime[jobs[i][0]] += 1;   
       }

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < waitTime.length; i++)
       {
        if(waitTime[i] > longestWait)
        {
         longestWait = waitTime[i];
         nextJob = i;
        }
       } jobsource.cycle(nextJob);waitTime[nextJob] = 0;

Answer (score 0):

While a array based solution 'may' work, I would advocate a more object oriented approach. Create 'Job' class with the desire attributes (id, start_time, wait etc). Using the csv file, create Job objects and hold them in a list. Write a comparator to sort this jobs-list (in this case based on job wait/age would be the factor).

The job executor then has to do the following:

```
while(jobs exist) {
  iterate on the list {
    if job is executable // start_time > current sys_time
    consume cycles/job for executable jobs
    mark completed jobs (optional)
  }    
  remove the completed jobs
}
```

Comment: for this I am unable to alter the Jobs class, i can only (get(id,durationLeft,priority) from each job and I can run a job for one cycle. This would be much easier if I could alter the job class. I pretty much need to create a class with a main method and somehow store a wait time variable for each job.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //\ This loop will add +1 to each job
    for(int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++)
    {
        waitTime[jobs[i][0]] += 1;          
    }

int longestWait = 0;//\ This holds value for greatest wait time
int nextJob = 0; //\ This holds value for index of job with greatest wait time

    //\ this loop will check for the greatest wait time and and set variables accordingly
    for(int i = 0; i < waitTime.length; i++)
    {
        if(waitTime[i] > longestWait)
    {
            longestWait = waitTime[i];
            nextJob = i;
    }
    }

    //\ this cycles the job with the highest wait time
    jobsource.cycle(nextJob);

    //\ this resets the wait time for processed job
    waitTime[nextJob] = 0;
```

Comment: This seems to do the job.